# How to search text file and return all items that containing the user input string

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

The text file has on each line the book title, author, publisher, date, and genre,  in that order, of all bestselling books in alphabetical order. I want to be able to search this text file by author or title to be able to print all the books with the author ("Name of book by author") that are containing that string the has been entered.

```
def author_search():
    author_string = input('Enter a title')
    lower_author = author_string.lower()
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as book_file:
        for line in book_file:
            if 'lower_title' in line:
                print(line)


def title_search():
    title_string = input('Enter a title')
    lower_title = title_string.lower()
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as book_file:
        for line in book_file:
            if 'lower_title' in line:
                print(line)
```

I'm not getting any errors but I'm also not getting any output when I run it with my main function

```
def main():
    run = True
    while run:
        book_file = open('file.txt', 'r')
        print('What would you like to do? ')
        print('1: Look up year range')
        print('2:Look up month/year')
        print('3:Search for author')
        print('4:Search for title')
        print('Q: Quit')
        userOp = input('Select an operation by entering its number: ')
        book_file = open('file.txt', 'r')
        if userOp == 1:
            print(year_range(book_file))
        if userOp == 2: 
            print(month_year(book_file))
        elif userOp == 3:
            print(author_search(book_file))
        elif userOp == 4:
            print(title_search(book_file))
     runCheck = input('Do you want to run another operation? ')
        if runCheck.lower == 'Q':
            run = False
            print('Goodbye')
```

It asks me to select and operation and then immediately asks me if I want to run another operation.

```
A Dance With Dragons    George R. R. Martin Bantam   7/31/2011   Fiction
A Day Late and a Dollar Short   Terry McMillan  Viking  2/4/2001    Fiction
A Feast For Crows   George R. R. Martin Bantam  11/27/2005  Fiction
A Lion Is In the Streets    Adria Locke Langley McGraw  7/1/1945    Fiction
A Man In Full   Tom Wolfe   Farrar, Straus & Giroux 11/22/1998  Fiction
```

Comment: Well for one, you have a syntax error in your `main()` function; there's an out of place `'` in `book_file = open(file.txt', 'r')`

Comment: Also, please post a few lines of your text file, so we can understand the syntax...

Comment: Also, `if 'lower_title' in line:` should be `if lower_title in line:` and `if lower_author in line:`. You're telling Python to look for the string `'lower_title'` instead of the user input.

Comment: I added a few of them

Comment: Also I'm just realizing I can't just search the line, I have to search the author and title columns exclusively because if I want to search an author, Harry, it would return Harry Potter to me as well, right?

Comment: You have two functions and both do exactly the same. Either make it a simple "search_any" function which just looks for the string, or make a parser which differentiates between author and title.